# PyQt4 : QPainter and QGraphicsSvgItem

Tags: svg, pyqt4

I'm not familiar with SVG, so I can get the concept of it.
I will draw items on QGraphicsScene.
With QGraphicsScene's method (like addRect, addLine, etc.) I can draw.
But it is just a drawing, it can't interact with users.
And then, someone told me that SVG can solve it.
So, I research "SVG" and read the related document, but I can't understand.
QGraphicsSvgItem needs "*.svg" files... right?
I just want to draw a rectangle in real time.
Can QPainter or something convert to QGraphicsSvgItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that someone misled you. QGraphicsSVGItem is used to add .svg (scalable vector graphics, i think) files to your QGraphicsScene.

You didn't mention what kind of interaction you need but here is a reply anyways:

QGraphicsItems have item [flags](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) that can modify the behaviour of the items. If these flags do not solve your needs, you can always subclass QGraphicsItem and override virtual methods like [mousePressEvent](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent), [wheelEvent](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#wheelEvent) etc.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I research QGraphicsItem and so on. And I think I can go trough with them. :)